# Method reference giving run time error, where as Supplier Interface works

Tags: java-8, method-reference

I have following code to generate summary for the list of values(Integer for this example). When I use method reference to get the values it is failing at run time giving ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException, but supplier is working fine.

static void test1() {

```
List<Integer> intList = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
IntSummaryStatistics stWorking = intList.stream().collect(Collectors.summarizingInt(num -> num));
System.out.println(stWorking);

IntSummaryStatistics stRuntimeError = intList.stream().collect(Collectors.summarizingInt(intList::get));
System.out.println(stRuntimeError);
```

}

Can somebody please help to understand what is the reason for this?

Thanks.

Comment: `intList::get` when the element is 2 is bound to blow up. Read the linked question.

Comment: The linked answer explains ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException but I am not accessing the list/array by the index. I am trying to understand what's the reason that the code with Method Ref doesn't work but the supplier function works. I tried with more elements but its still failing.

Comment: Yes, yes you are. `intList::get` can be written `num -> intList.get(num)`. So when `num = 2`: BOOM. (or `num = 5` with your edit)

Comment: Oh now I get it. Thanks.